# Firebase cloud messaging shows There was an error loading targeting options

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used Firebase cloud messaging to send the notification to the users but from last one week i am getting this error while targetting the App
**There was an error loading targeting options.**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem. Interesting thing, that message was shown when I switch to topic, play with it and when I returned back got that message.

So, I save as draft my notification, because I don't want to lose my filled data. Reload page or open again and now it is work as expected.